# uSiteBuilder Template not showing in list of templates in the backend of umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, umbraco, umbraco7

I've been experimenting with uSiteBuilder and umbraco v7 in VS 2012. I'm trying to create masterpages as templates in umbraco. I've already created a corresponding doctype:

```
[DocumentType(
    Name="Homepage", 
    Alias="homepage", 
    AllowAtRoot=true)]

public class Homepage : DocumentTypeBase
{

}
```

According to their tutorials http://usitebuilder.vegaitsourcing.rs/tutorials?id=22391 i should now be able to create masterpages as templates. So i created the following masterpage:

```
[Template(AllowedForDocumentType=true)]
public partial class Homepage : TemplateBase<MySite.Homepage>
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

When i compile there are no errors or whatsoever, but the template does not show up in the list of templates in the backend?! Has anybody experienced the same problems, and is there a solution? Or am i missing something here?